# javafx SimpleIntegerProperty get() does not return set value

Tags: javafx, properties, thread-safety

I am investigating a strange situation where a JavaFX's SimpleIntegerProperty does not return the correct value from time to time. I have googled a lot but haven't found any hint about the issue. I know that these properties are not thread safe but in this case the same thread is doing the set() and get() methods which can be seen in the code below.

There is a model class "Customer" in which the SimpleIntegerProperty is a member variable of:

```
public class Customer {

private  SimpleIntegerProperty adr_nr = new SimpleIntegerProperty();



private void queryDataFromDatabase(int adr_nr, Connection connection) throws AdrNrNotFoundException{

    Connection con = connection;

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sadr_nr = String.valueOf(adr_nr);

    try{

        String sqlgrunddat = "select adr_nr, adr_name1, adr_name2"
                + " from customer"
                + " where adr_nr="+sadr_nr;


        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlgrunddat);



        while(rs.next()){

            this.adr_nr.set(rs.getInt(1));


        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

        if (this.adr_nr.get()<1){

            throw new AdrNrNotFoundException();

        }


    }
    catch (SQLException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
}
```

The issue which occurs intermittently is that the `AdrNrNotFoundException` is thrown allthough `ResultSet` has returned a correct integer-value and the property has been successfully set before. So when I set a breakpoint before the exception is thrown, I can see that my SimpleIntegerProperty adr_nr has a correct value (e.g. 20532).

It looks like that the `adr_nr.get()` method does intermittently return 0 - otherwise the if would return false. As I said the thing about thread safety should not be the problem in this case because the `set()` and `get()` methods of the property are called within the same method which runs on the same thread.

Changing the code from

```
        if (this.adr_nr.get()<1){

            throw new AdrNrNotFoundException();

        }
```

to

```
        if (this.adr_nr.get()==0){

            throw new AdrNrNotFoundException();

        }
```

doesn't change the situation.

If I use a primitive `int` as a workaround, the issue won't occur. I'm using JDK 8 update 121.

Hope that somebody has an idea...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a method argument named `adr_nr` as well. Are you sure you're not looking at it in the debugger. instead of the class member?  Try changing the name of one of them.

Comment: Well I see the value if I hoover with my mouse over "this.adr_nr" and there I see the "value" property...